# Click back button on browser shows raw script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html5-history

There are some ajax calls in a page. What i have done is used history api to update the history. In the page /test i make a ajax request which updates the history and url is set to /test?query=true. On the pop state the ajax call is made according to the current url.

```
// Called in click event for the ajax call to create the history.
      var stateObj = { query: 'query' };
      history.pushState(stateObj, null, ?query=true);

// Called on the popstate
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: window.location.href,
        dataType: 'script'
    });
}
```

Now when i have the state pused and url updated to /test?query=true i go to some other page /test2 and click browser back button the browser shows me the raw js code from my js.erb file.